# Set a column to one date format Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multiple-columns

I am filtering out records for last month data records, however when doing

```
emp_df = emp_df[emp_df['Date'].dt.month == (currentMonth-1)]
```

It neglects some records(treats some records months as days).[Link to File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d3e59afaf6f44f824410998fc3df96a720221115104137/3e78f1)

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cholareport = pd.read_excel("D:/Automations/HealthCheck and Audit Trail/report.xlsx")
uniqueemp = set(cholareport['Email'])
cholareport['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(cholareport['Date'])

uniqueemp = set(cholareport['Email'])
daystoignore = ['Holiday_COE', 'Leave_COE']
# datedfforemp = pd.DataFrame(columns=uniqueemp)
cholareport['Date'] = cholareport['Date'].apply(lambda x: 
pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
cholareport["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(cholareport["Date"], utc=True)

for emp in uniqueemp:
    emp_df = cholareport[cholareport['Email'].isin([emp])]
    emp_df = emp_df[~emp_df['Task: Task Name'].isin(daystoignore)]
    # s1 = pd.to_datetime(emp_df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
    # s2 = (pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m') -pd.DateOffset(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m')
    # emp_df = emp_df[s1 == s2]
    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    # print(currentMonth)
    # print(emp_df['Date'])
    emp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(emp_df['Date']).dt.strftime("%dd-%mm-%YYYY")
    format_data = "%dd-%mm-%YYYY"
    empdfdate = []
    for i in emp_df['Date']:
        empdfdate.append(datetime.strptime(i,format_data))
    print(empdfdate)
    emp_df['Date'] = empdfdate
    for i in emp_df['Date']:
        print(i.month, i.day)

    # emp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(emp_df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
    emp_df = emp_df[emp_df['Date'].dt.month == (currentMonth-1)]
    
    for i in emp_df['Date']:
        print(i.month, i.day)
```

Results :
6 10
7 10
10 10
11 10
12 10
10 13
10 14
Expected:
6 10
7 10
10 10
11 10
12 10
13 10
14 10

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to accomplish. If I understand it correctly, you simply want to count the number of entries per day for the past month. In such case, you can simply do the following.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

report = pd.read_excel('report.xlsx')

print('day: counts', report.Date[report.Date.dt.month == datetime.now().month - 1].dt.day.value_counts(), sep='\n')
```

I do not get your expected results. It might be that you also want to filter by email somehow; however, I cannot understand from your code what it is that you want to do.

Output:

```
day: counts
3     101
5     101
6     101
7     101
4     101
24     84
28     84
27     84
26     84
25     84
10     82
11     82
12     82
13     82
14     82
17     67
21     67
20     67
19     67
18     67
31      2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: the data has records from Sept, Oct, and a few records from Nov, I am trying to filter out records from Oct, but when I filter them as mentioned in the problem, it removes a few entries of Oct considering it to be of some other months. 
i.e 3 Oct(3-10), it is neglecting considering it as 10-Mar(10-3). 

So if there is some solution that can help me to change the format of dataframe{'Date'}.

Comment: But how do you know that 3-10 is 3rd of October and not 10th of March? Is this because you only have data from September to November? What if you had data from the entire year? Then you would have no clue what dates are correct.